# TimeSlice or requestData on mediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript, mediarecorder

I have an application running with electron/react/ffmpeg for live streaming

mediaRecorder.start(3000)

3000ms is the same time as the TS file size I want

I'm having problems in some sporadic cases that apparently the ondataavaliable method is never called, I would like to know what can I do?

If there is any difference between mediaRecoder.start(3000), or making a timeout function every 3s with requestData?

I haven't modified the code yet, I'm trying to research more about it to make a decision than to actually do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.